# Pasting cells from table into an Excel form

Tags: vba, excel

So I am new to writing macros so please pardon any ignorance on my part. I have looked through many online resources to find a similar code but nothing that matches what I am needing.

I am attempting to create a form within excel that auto-populates with data entered into a separate worksheet. The data sheet `WorkSheet("Results")` has the data stored across the row with the first cell in the `Row(Column A)` being the data identifier. The form sheet `WorkSheet("Audit Form")` needs the data identifier entered to populate the fields throughout the form.

What I am needing is a code that will loop through the cells in `Column A`, enter them into the field on the Audit Form, and then copy the `WorkSheet("Audit Form")` to a new WorkBook, cycling through each row in the table on the `WorkSheet("Results")`. This will be driven by a button that will execute the macro once selected. Preferably the code will ignore hidden fields within the table, if a user were to use a filter on it.
So far, the code I have written will cycle through the rows in `Column A` and paste them to the required field in the Audit Form, and it will copy the `WorkSheet("Audit Form")` to a new WorkBook but the Audit Forms being compiled into the new WorkBook only have the data identifier from the first `Row("A2")`, so each copied Audit Form shows the same data.

I am certain I am missing some small code that will correct this and I appreciate any advice that you may provide!

```
Sub testbutton()
    Dim incell As Range, outcel As Range
    Set outcel = Worksheets("Results").Range("A2")
    Set incell = Sheets("Audit Form").Range("F29")
    Do
        incell.Value = outcel.Value
        Sheets("Audit Form").Copy Before:=Workbooks("Book1").Sheets(1)
        Set outcel = outcel.Offset(1, 0)        
    Loop 
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show how your data is organized? I think this can be simplified without looping. Show the source data (simplified) and then the form or template worksheet you want populated. You can upload screen shot in any free image hosting site (e.g http://imgur.com) and then post the link in your question.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and break up the huge wall of text to include some paragraph breaks? When you're talking, you pause to take a breath occasionally; you should do so when writing as well.

Comment: How about just adding Set incell = incell.Offset(1, 0)?

Comment: So you realize you have a loop that does no looping?  Neither the Do nor the Loop defines any criteria to perform a loop.  It just "falls through" just once.  So indeed you appear to only be copying "Results!A2" into "Audit Form!F29" ... just that one cell.  You have no loop to "loop through the cells in Column A" to quote your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the valuable feedback guys.

However, it seems I was able to solve my own question.

For your reference, the below code is what I was able to put together to work.

Thanks again!

```html
Sub testbutton2()

Dim outcel As Range, incel As Range, rng As Range

Set outcel = Worksheets("Results").Range("A2")
Set incel = Worksheets("Audit Form").Range("F29")
Set rng = Worksheets("Results").Range("A2:A233")


For Each outcel In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   

    outcel.Copy
    Sheets("Audit Form").Range("F29").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Sheets("Audit Form").Copy Before:=Workbooks("Book1").Sheets(1)
    
Next outcel
    
    
End Sub
```